# MSSQL Parsing of XML that Contains same Sibling

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I am trying to query a MSSQL database that has XML and parse it out.

here is the data:

```
<Root>
<Relatives>
<Relative>
  <Relation>Father</Relation>
  <BcAge>50</BcAge>
  <BilatAge>0</BilatAge>
  <OcAge>0</OcAge>
</Relative>
<Relative>
  <Relation>Mother</Relation>
  <BcAge>58</BcAge>
  <BilatAge>0</BilatAge>
  <OcAge>0</OcAge>
</Relative>
```

Here is the desired result

```
Relation BcAge BilatAge OcAge Relation BcAge BilatAge OcAge 
Father   50     0       0      Mother  58    0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt, that you really want to get your result *side-by-side*... This is no valid resultset, your column names are duplicated.

If you really need it this way you might do this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Root>
<Relatives>
<Relative>
  <Relation>Father</Relation>
  <BcAge>50</BcAge>
  <BilatAge>0</BilatAge>
  <OcAge>0</OcAge>
</Relative>
<Relative>
  <Relation>Mother</Relation>
  <BcAge>58</BcAge>
  <BilatAge>0</BilatAge>
  <OcAge>0</OcAge>
</Relative>
</Relatives>
</Root>';
```

The query will use a CTE to get the Father and the Mother with an `XQuery-predicate`

```sql
WITH Parents AS
(
    SELECT @xml.query(N'/Root/Relatives/Relative[(Relation/text())[1]="Father"]') AS Father
          ,@xml.query(N'/Root/Relatives/Relative[(Relation/text())[1]="Mother"]') AS Mother
)
SELECT 'Father' AS F_Relation
      ,Father.value(N'(/Relative/BcAge)[1]',N'int') AS F_BcAge
      ,Father.value(N'(/Relative/BilatAge)[1]',N'int') AS F_BilatAge
      ,Father.value(N'(/Relative/OcAge)[1]',N'int') AS F_OcAge
      ,'Mother' AS M_Relation   
      ,Mother.value(N'(/Relative/BcAge)[1]',N'int') AS M_BcAge
      ,Mother.value(N'(/Relative/BilatAge)[1]',N'int') AS M_BilatAge
      ,Mother.value(N'(/Relative/OcAge)[1]',N'int') AS M_OcAge
FROM Parents;
```

But probably it's this you are looking for (any count of `<Relative>`):

```sql
SELECT rel.value(N'(Relation/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Relation
      ,rel.value(N'(BcAge/text())[1]',N'int') AS BcAge
      ,rel.value(N'(BilatAge/text())[1]',N'int') AS BilatAge
      ,rel.value(N'(OcAge/text())[1]',N'int') AS OcAge
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Root/Relatives/Relative') AS A(rel)
```